# min-height and min-width not working

Tags: html, css

My html code

```
<div style="width: 75%; height: auto; min-height: 235px !important; float: left; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">

    <table style=" display: inline-block;margin-left: -4px;" class="blue-column-background step-eight-middle-table step-eight-table">
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.feed_time %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.quantity %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.unit %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.feed_act %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.daily_feed_and_care_instruction %> <%= "this is to test this is to test this is to test" if ( i == 3 ) %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.location %></th></tr>
              <tr class="each-table-row"><th class="each-table-column"><%= horse.assigned_user_id %></th></tr>

            </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.step-eight-middle-table tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #227BA6 !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-right: 1px solid #227BA6 !important;

  padding-left: 4px;
  max-width: 125px !important;
  min-height: 30px !important;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

For this code min-height and max-width is not working at all though height and width are working as expected. Why these are not working?

Comment: Why do you have inline styles at all if you are using classes? Its hard to even see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: looks like [it's working](http://jsfiddle.net/5XpD6/)... could you specify exactly what unexpected result you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply min-height to table-cells, just apply a height and it will grow if it needs to.

Same goes for max-width - if you need a max width you will need to put a div inside the table cell and add the max width to that

By the way, you seem to be applying a max width to the tr so why not just set a width of 100% for your table and apply a max-width to your container div?

Comment: How come you can't apply min-height? This is a serious question by the way

Comment: @Haydn_JW The spec [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights) that `min-height` is applicable to *"all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups"*.